# Why does folding@home not recognize my Nvidia GPU on Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia

The control software says there are 0 GPUs even though I am sure my Nvidia is working and actually running. Even Cuda is correctly installed.

The GPU is a Nvidia 1050Ti running on Ubuntu 18.04 with driver version 440.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. I actually ran into this issue. If there are any comments e.g. on this question being wrong or sth please feel free to write them and I will change the text. Nevertheless I found the answer after half an hour of searching in forums and wanted to spare other people from that experience.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently GPUs are disabled by default on Ubuntu (Linux in general?). The solution can be found here: https://foldingforum.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=30195

> Open FAHControl, go to the configuration tab and then the expert tab, you will see an argument; gpu that has false next to it, click on it and input true in the value box. The client should now download gpu.txt. Reboot and you should be good to go.

After doing this the GPU should be found correctly if it is set up correctly. To make it work you still have to add a GPU slot in Configure > Slots > Add > Add your GPU and save.